# One project, different setting (Such as bundle id and app name)

Tags: ios, xcode, version-control

I'm working on an iPad Project.

With this project, it has been built and ad-hoc/appstore release for multiple clients. The different among all of those apps are the following

- Bundle Identifier
- Bundle Version (Number and String)
- Icon File
- Application Name

Now, let's say, I'm having 5 branches which are

- Master
- Development
- App 1 (Name "App 1", Bundle ID "com.company.app1", Version "1.0", Icon "App1.png")
- App 2 (Name "App 2", Bundle ID "com.company.app2", Version "1.3", Icon "App2.png")
- App 3 (Name "App 3", Bundle ID "com.company.app3", Version "1.6", Icon "App3.png")

What I did before was doing all the new feature implementation in Development branch and then

- merge into Master and push to repository
- merge into App 1, App 2 and App 3

But, the problem is, when I merged any change from development into any other branch, I had to manually set Bundle Identifier and else.

So, the question is, how can I preserve those value not to be replaced once I do branch merging?

**P.S.** one solution I can think of is that to create multiple project for each of the client and ignore the file that contains those value, but, I wanna know if there is any other suitable solution or not.

Comment: You should try adding the file with the extension .xcodeproj to your .gitignore file

Comment: The question is that, is it save to do so?